# angular 6 display templates dynamically based on type

Tags: angular, templates

I am having a svg in which I want to display several kind of shapes like line, circle etc. Below is an example of creating a single line and display it in the svg.

In my AppComponent I want to iterate over the shapes list and display the svg component using a template but nothing is displayed. What am I doing wrong ?

Each Component should have its own template to display in the svg

In this example the shapes is holding only a LineComponent but can be also a CircleComponent, RectangleComponent etc.

I have this AppComponent

```
import { Component, ContentChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

import { LineComponent } from './components/line/line.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'svg-drawing-tool';

    shapes: LineComponent[];
    visible: boolean = true;

    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) shapeTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor');
        this.shapes = [];
        this.createLines();
    }

    private createLines(): void {
        var l1: LineComponent = new LineComponent();
        this.shapes.push(l1);
        console.log('shapes:', this.shapes);
    }

    onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
        console.log('mouse down svg');
    }
}
```

and my html is

```
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)">
        <ng-template ngFor let-line [ngForOf]="shapes" [ngForTemplate]="shapeTemplate"></ng-template>
    </svg>
</div>
```

and my LineComponent is

```
import { Component, OnInit, ContentChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Line } from '../../model/shape';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-line',
    templateUrl: './line.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./line.component.css']
})
export class LineComponent implements OnInit {

    line: Line;

    constructor() {
        console.log('LineComponent constructor');
        this.line = new Line(100, 100, 200, 200);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('LineComponent ngOnInit');
    }

}
```

My LineComponent template is (Line is a class which holds the properties of a line i.e. startpoint and endpoint and color)

```
<ng-template #shapeTemplate>
    <svg:line attr.x1="{{ line.x1 }}" attr.y1="{{ line.y1 }}" attr.x2="{{ line.x2 }}"
        attr.y2="{{ line.y2 }}" style="stroke:#006600; stroke-width:5px" />
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display ng-templates from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379006/how-to-display-ng-templates-from-list)