# How to display ng-templates from list

Tags: angular, ng-template

I have an `AppComponent` which holds a list of `ShapeComponents`. I implemented some Components which extends the `ShapeComponent` like `LineComponent`, `CircleComponent`, `RectangleComponent`. Each of them has its own `ng-template` with `#shapeTemplate`.
In my `app.component.html` I want to iterate over the list of `ShapeComponents` and display each `ng-template` (from `LineComponent`, `CircleComponent` etc).

so I have

```
shapes: ShapeComponent[] = []
```

which hold a LineComponent, CircleComponent etc

I want to something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let shape of shapes">
    <!-- How to display the ng-template from for example LineComponent or Circle -->
</div>
```

I thought using @ViewChildren or @ContentChildren would be useful but no idea how to deal with that

Comment: Could you share code of `ShapeComponent`?

Comment: This is a hard question, because testing an object's type in the template requires getting the object's type as a string—but in production, all of your class names might be minified, so testing class name might be a really bad idea.  You might have to opt for `instanceof` calls in your component for each possible `ShapeComponent` derivative.

Comment: can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: How does your `AppComponent` gets a list of `ShapeComponent`s?

Comment: I posted an answer, it may be just what you need

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/UVHBdBcSRbgSUjXqC73T?open=app%2Fshapes.ts

Comment: @yurzui you are right, did not see that

Answer (score 5):

I've done something similar recently. Here is the final [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggft6v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

First, I create a ShapeComponent

```
import { 
  Component, 
  Input, 
  ViewChild, 
  TemplateRef 
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'shape',
  template: `<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>`,
})
export class ShapeComponent  {

  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

It's template has a `ng-template` so that we can ref to it, and `ng-content` so consumers of this component can project their content in.

With `@ViewChild(TemplateRef)` you can get a reference of `ng-template` and whatever is inside of it because of `ng-content`.

Let's create a `LineComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'line',
  template: `<ng-template>
    This is line and its content: <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template>`,
  providers: [{
    provide: ShapeComponent,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => LineComponent)
  }]
})
export class LineComponent extends ShapeComponent  {}
```

and `CircleComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'circle',
  template: `<ng-template>
    This is circle and its content: <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template>`,
  providers: [{
    provide: ShapeComponent,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CircleComponent)
  }]
})
export class CircleComponent extends ShapeComponent  {}
```

Both components extend `ShapeComponent` and provide it according to themselves. So that whenever someone tries to inject `ShapeComponent`, they will get a `LineComponent` or a `ShapeComponent`.

Finally, let's create a `ShapeHolderComponent` which will glue all this together

```
@Component({
  selector: 'shape-holder',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let child of children">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="child.template"></ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ShapeHolderComponent  {

  @ContentChildren(ShapeComponent) children: QueryList<ShapeComponent>;
}
```

You can list of `ShapeComponent`s with `ContentChildren`. Since, every `ShapeComponent` provides themselves, we can get a list of them and use their `template`s.

Finally, let's use all of this within `AppComponent`

```
<shape-holder>
  <circle>
    Custom Circle content
  </circle>
  <line>
    Custom Line content
  </line>
</shape-holder>
```

The output is

```
This is circle and its content: Custom Circle content
This is line and its content: Custom Line content
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot you are great. I upgrade this answer to give you points.

Comment: Almost ok. I want an array of ShapeComponents and iterate over them. I do not want to add seperate selectors like line or circle to appear in my app-component.

Comment: @baliman do you retrieve this array from backend or something? How do you differentiate between lines, circles etc.?

Comment: So ShapeHolder component I have a shapes array

shapes: ShapeComponent[];

    constructor() {
        this.shapes = [];
        this.shapes.push(new LineComponent());
        this.shapes.push(new CircleComponent());
        console.log('shapes:', this.shapes)
    }

So i want iterate over the shapes array and display the linecomponent or circlecomponent template

Comment: This is the one thing, after hours of searching, that does what I want. Thank you!

Comment: This is perfect @BunyaminCoskuner!

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to display components, but it is quite complex and not my recommendation.

The "angular-style" solution for your issue is this:

1. Use a list of model objects (not components), containing all information that the sub-components need. Let's call it `models` in this example.
2. Store the type of the shape in a property of each of these models (avoids having to use `typeOf`). Let's call if `shape`. You could also use an enumeration, if you prefer.
3. Iterate over the models in a `ngFor` and create a component for each one of them.

The HTML-Template might look like this

```
<div *ngFor="let model of models">

    <!-- display the ng-template from for example LineComponent or Circle -->
    <line   [model]="model" *ngIf="model.shape === 'Line'"></line>
    <circle [model]="model" *ngIf="model.shape === 'Circle'"></circle>

</div>
```

See the full, working example [on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsdwgf).

Comment: Where does `typeOf` come from?

Comment: @AlexPeters I changed the solution to avoid `typeOf` anyways.

Comment: Given the use of class names in a string, would this approach continue to work in production after potential minifying of code (and class names)?

Comment: @AlexPeters I would suggest to not rely on class names at all. Only strings or enumeration constants would probably be *easy* and *robust*.

Comment: This is close to what I want. But I thought you can use ng-template.

Comment: `ng-template` could be used inside the `line`- or `circle`-Component for to refer to their tag's content. For example: if you use `<line [model]=...>Bla</line>` in the html-template of AppComponent, then you can access `Bla` as `<ng-template>` in the html-template of LineComponent.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Actually I found an excellent post on github

https://github.com/shivs25/angular5-canvas-drawer. I took this solution to implement my own.

So all the credits go to Billy Shivers. Well done.

Here is the solution

The settings for line and circle can be dynamic set, below is just an example of a line and circle

CircleComponent and HTML template

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ShapeComponent } from '../shape/shape.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-circle',
    templateUrl: './circle.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./circle.component.css']
})
export class CircleComponent extends ShapeComponent {

    constructor() {
        super('circle');
    }
}
```

html

```
<ng-template #elementTemplate>
    <svg:circle [attr.cx]="50" [attr.cy]="50" [attr.r]="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</ng-template>>
```

LineComponent and HTML template

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ShapeComponent } from '../shape/shape.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-line',
    templateUrl: './line.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./line.component.css']
})
export class LineComponent extends ShapeComponent {

    constructor() {
        super('line');
        console.log('linecomponent:constructor');
    }

}
```

html

```
<ng-template #elementTemplate>
    <svg:line [attr.x1]="100" [attr.y1]="100" [attr.x2]="200" [attr.y2]="200" style="stroke:#006600; stroke-width:1px" />
</ng-template>>
```

The ShapeComponent and HTML

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-shape',
    templateUrl: './shape.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./shape.component.css']
})
export class ShapeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    shapeType: string;
    visible: boolean = true;

    id: string = 'unknown';

    @ViewChild('elementTemplate')
    elementTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor(shapeType: string) {
        console.log('shapecomponent constructor :', shapeType);
        this.shapeType = shapeType;
    }

    setid(value: string): void {
        this.id = value;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('ShapeComponent ngOnInit()');
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log('!!!!!!!!! ShapeComponent ngAfterViewInit: ', this.elementTemplate);
    }

}
```

html : none

The enum for component types

```
export enum ShapeTypes {
    Line,
    Circle,
    Rectangle
}
```

The ShapeHolderComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ShapeComponent } from '../shape/shape.component';
import { LineComponent } from '../line/line.component';
import { CircleComponent } from '../circle/circle.component';
import { ShapeTypes } from '../model/shape-types';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-shapeholder',
    templateUrl: './shapeholder.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./shapeholder.component.css']
})
export class ShapeholderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('elementTemplate')
    elementTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

    shapes: ShapeTypes[];

    constructor() {
        this.shapes = [];
        this.shapes.push(ShapeTypes.Line);
        this.shapes.push(ShapeTypes.Circle);
        console.log('shapeholder shapes :', this.shapes);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('ShapeHolderComponent : ngOnInit()');
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log('!!!!!!!!! ShapeHolder ngAfterViewInit: ', this.elementTemplate);
    }

}
```

html, set height in width in css for the svg

```
<svg>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let shape of shapes; let i = index">
        <ng-container svg-dynamic [componentData]="shape">
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</svg>
```

And the most import part of it, the directive

```
import { Directive, Input, ViewContainerRef, Injector, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { ShapeComponent } from './shape/shape.component';
import { LineComponent } from './line/line.component';
import { CircleComponent } from './circle/circle.component';
import { ShapeTypes } from './model/shape-types';

@Directive({
    selector: '[svg-dynamic]'
})
export class SvgDynamicDirective {

    constructor(private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

    }

    @Input() set componentData(data: ShapeTypes) {
        console.log('set componentdata : ', data);

        let injector = Injector.create([], this._viewContainerRef.parentInjector);
        console.log('injector:', injector);
        let factory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.buildComponent(data));
        console.log('factory:', factory);
        let component = factory.create(injector);
        console.log('component:', component);
        let c: ShapeComponent = <ShapeComponent>component.instance;

        console.log('viewContainerRef:', this._viewContainerRef);
        console.log('elementTemplate:', c.elementTemplate);
        this._viewContainerRef.clear();
        this._viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(c.elementTemplate);
    }

    private buildComponent(data: ShapeTypes): any {
        switch (data) {
            case ShapeTypes.Line:
                return LineComponent;
            case ShapeTypes.Circle:
                return CircleComponent;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And the app.component html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
        Welcome to {{ title }}!
    </h1>
    <app-shapeholder></app-shapeholder>
</div>
```

The app.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'demo1';
}
```

And the app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ShapeComponent } from './shape/shape.component';
import { LineComponent } from './line/line.component';
import { ShapeholderComponent } from './shapeholder/shapeholder.component';
import { SvgDynamicDirective } from './svg-dynamic.directive';
import { CircleComponent } from './circle/circle.component';

@NgModule({
    entryComponents: [
        LineComponent,
        ShapeComponent,
        CircleComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LineComponent,
        ShapeComponent,
        CircleComponent,
        ShapeholderComponent,
        SvgDynamicDirective,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And a final screen shot of my app

[image]

I hope you find this answer usefull and can use it in your own app. The idea is to create dynamic templates views

Comment: Looks like the same approach I posted in comments to your question

Answer (score 0):

In this case the best and also officially suggested approach is to use [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).

In the documentation you'll find some useful tips

Comment: Is this answer intended for a different question?

Comment: not really, with the same approach you can instantiate different component per each shape

Comment: Ah yes, I see now, particularly around the `DynamicFormQuestionComponent` example.  Got it.